# How to avoid multiple loops for comparison with each array item

Tags: c#, .net

I had one array containing the credit limit of customers for example [28,32,63] and one array containing the items value example [48,35]. Now only customer with credit limit  of 63 can buy either one of the food item with 48 or 35 and neither first nor second customer with credit limit of 28 and 32 can buy any items. I can compare the items and using the for loop and then find the count For example.

```
int[] custCredit={28,32,63}; 
int[] ItemVal={48,35};
Dictionary<string,bool> objDict=new Dictionary<string,bool>();
for(int n=1;n<=custCredit.Length;n++)
   {
    for(int m=1;m<=ItemVal.Length;m++)
    {
      if(n>=m)
      {
           objDict.Add(n.ToString()+m.ToString(),true);
      };
    }
   }
```

Now I can find all the values with true in dictionary to find out the max number of customers and items they can buy. 
Now is it possible to do this with only one loop ?

Comment: What do you mean one loop?  you will always need both `for` loops and your dictionary(why dictionary, just `List` should be enough here) already should contain only keys with values `true`, based on the code which you have added.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using List. Is there any way possible that I can use Linq (I don't know linq) to minimise this code.

Comment: You probably should use some other way of identifying the customers instead of using their "credit limit" for that purpose. What are going to do when there are 2 customers with the same "credit limit"?

Comment: Please update your question as it's about converting the loops of your solution into lambda.

Answer (score 2):

use Linq;

```
int[] custCredit = { 28, 32, 63 };
int[] ItemVal = { 48, 35 };
var result = custCredit.SelectMany((c, cidx) => ItemVal.Where(i => c >= i).Select((i, iidx) => $"{cidx}{iidx}"));
```

if you need it as Dictionary with the true:

```
result.ToDictionary(k => k, v => true)
```

Comment: How is this avoiding the loops mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Ghukas check his comment. he asked for a linq solution in the comment.

Comment: @user3104267 I see `SelectMany` with a `Where` and a`Select` in it. ‍♂️

Comment: @Blechdose, thanks. OP needs to update the question then.

Comment: @Ghukas I think the whole question is a mess and confusing. it needs a complete overhaul. it mixes array indices with array values: if(n>m) makes no sense for example.  the answeres presented so far are showing the creditLimits and itemValues combined in a string, but he probably wanted to have the indices in the arrays.... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the syntax in @user3104267's answer, you can also write as:

```
int[] custCredit = { 28, 32, 63 };
int[] ItemVal = { 48, 35 };

var results =
    from credit in custCredit
    from item in ItemVal
    where credit >= item
    select credit.ToString() + " can buy " + item.ToString();

foreach (var r in results) Console.WriteLine(r);
```